# Max SD Card Size For Note Edge

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, storage, internal-sd

I have a 16 GB SD Card in my `Galaxy Note Edge` and only have 1GB of storage left.  I read that some Android devices can only hold up to 32GB - can my phone support the 64GB card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

[Galaxy Note Edge SM-915G user manual](http://www.samsung.com/in/support/model/SM-N915GZKEINS) says

> Your device accepts memory card with a maximum capacity of 128 GB

Also [in this review](http://www.cnet.com/news/samsung-to-galaxy-note-5-s6-edge-buyers-no-128gb-option-for-you/) (S6 Edge+ does NOT)

> Samsung does offer a 128GB option for its Galaxy S6 and Galaxy S6 Edge